How do I update my azure cloud service extended support using powershell?
All works well in my script until I get to the actual command.  My cloud service extended support is already created. I want to update it with the new csdef, cspkg, and cscfg files.  When I run this commands:
New-AzCloudService 
-Name "xxx" 
-ResourceGroupName "xxx" 
-Location "North Central US" 
-ConfigurationFile $cspkgFilePath 
-DefinitionFile $csdefFilePath 
-PackageURL $cspkgUrl

I get the following error:
A Cloud Service resource with name: 'xxx' already exists in Resource Group: 'xxx'. Please try another name.
I'm not trying to create a NEW cloud service, just trying to update the existing one.

To update the existing cloud service roles or configurations, you need to use the Update-AzCloudService PowerShell command as shown in the below way.
$cloudservice=Get-AzCloudService -ResourceGroupName "Jahnavi" -CloudServiceName "newclouds"
$cloudservice.Configuration
$updateddef="ServiceDefinition.csdef"
$content = Get-Content $updateddef | Out-String
$cloudservice.configuration=$content
$cloudservice | Update-AzCloudService


Note: New-AzCloudService is the command which is used to only creating the cloud service.
